# wireshark is not capturing http traffic

Tags: networking, wireshark

I have a lab server that I have a desktop that I would like to monitor with wireshark directly connected to and I am bridging the NICs to the internet connection between the server and the desktop. When try to do a packet capture on the network bridge, I don't see any network traffic from the desktop PC.

Any ideas on what I am missing here? I don't see any network traffic on the local connections, just the 'network bridge'.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important settings in WS that you should check before starts capturing:

1.) Capture => Capture filters

There is plus sign in the left bottom corner of the conversation panel. You can add more filters.

2.) Analyze => Display filters

You can set here up what you see during capture process.

If you cannot see HTTP packets these two are the responsible for. Check the filters first and if you can find HTTP among the filters check the display whether is set up to appear.